# sequelize connection hanging in bun

Tags: sequelize.js, bun

When using Sequelize with [bun](https://bun.sh) after finishing my queries and closing the connection it just hangs and the process doesn't exit.

The last message I get (DEBUG=sequelize*) is:

```
sequelize:pool connection drain due to process exit +0ms
```

Here is my code

```js
const results = await MyModel.findAll();
console.log(results)
await sequelize.connectionManager.close()
```

Any idea what it could be?

FYI I only managed to get sequelize to get this far by setting the `databaseVersion` option when creating the Sequelize instance.

Comment: What if you don't do `await sequelize.connectionManager.close()`?

Comment: I think it's this: https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/5902

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/5902
It seems that it is already fixed